# Is the "Declaring Classes" Java tutorial wrong about private classes?

Tags: java

I was reading the Java documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html) and this is what I found:

> You can also add modifiers like *public* or *private* at the very beginning—so you can see that the opening line of a class declaration can become quite complicated. The modifiers *public* and *private*, which determine what other classes can access `MyClass`, are discussed later in this lesson.

It specifies that I can create a class with the `private` or `public` modifiers. However, when I try to use the `private` modifier, I get an error that it is an illegal modifier for that class band: only `public`, `abstract` and `final` are permitted.

I understand that the `private` modifier is not useful, but why does this tutorial, which is from the official Java site, state that I can create a class using it? Did I miss something?

Comment: That's just a tutorial, not a docs or spec.

Comment: This is covered later in the same tutorial. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Well, I don't think it's fair to downvote this question. The question is quite justifiable, given that the resource OP is reading has given that information is much of a mis-leading way. It's true that, it has explained it correctly little later, but still not a good reason for downvote.

Answer (score 15):

Top level classes cannot be `private`. However, nested classes can be `private`.

See [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1)

> The access modifier public (§6.6) pertains only to top level classes
>   (§7.6) and to member classes (§8.5), not to local classes (§14.3) or
>   anonymous classes (§15.9.5).
>
> The access modifiers protected and private (§6.6) pertain only to
>   member classes within a directly enclosing class or enum declaration
>   (§8.5).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a `private` top level class. You *can* have a `private` inner or nested class.

Obviously a `private` top level class would be somewhat useless as you would not be allowed to access it from anywhere.

So this is allowed

```
public class MyClass {
    private class MyInnerClass {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a mistake; look at the wording very carefully:

You can also add modifiers ***like*** public or private at the very beginning-......

You can have public and default (package-private, no modifier word) visibility for *regular* classes. Nested ones can be private or proctected as well.

Comment: Well, wording of that statement doesn't make it really clear that it is talking about inner classes. So, it is quite misleading for beginners.

Comment: I agree, unless you look very closely it's very unclearly worded.

Answer (score 1):

"""Illegal modifier for the class ; only public, abstract & final are permitted .."""

***the top class cannot be private***

when you try to name the file using the name of the private class ..

you cannot use same name for the file and the private class..

class name and file name are same if and only class is not private,..

**if the class is public, then the file name and the class name should be same.**

if there are many public classes , the file name should be of the public class names ..
.

Comment: Did you try this before posting. You can't have your top-level class as private, whatever the file name is.

Comment: i know, but i was talking when we have two or more classes

Answer (score 0):

You can have a private inner class so it is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use them for Inner classes. I suspect you tried to use it for a top level class. [Here's an example of using private classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

The primary class in a .java file must not be private (it would be a worthless file for it to be private, after all how would it be used) however you can have inner classes that are used by the main class in the file, those can be private.

For example

```
public class OuterClass{

    //constructors and methods of OuterClass

    private class InnerClass{
           //constructors and methods of InnerClass
    }

}
```

Comment: @nachokk You do make a fair point (somewhat agressively but fair none the less), have corrected

Comment: never agressively im not native english speaker could be that

Comment: @nachokk No problem, thanks for the spot. I was concentrating on when private *could* be used and didn't pay attention to the public side of things

Answer (score 0):

Private classes are permitted, but only as inner or nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

`private` is allowed for nested classes:

```
public class A {
    private B b;
    private class B {} // Only class A can use this class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always have inner class as private.

Below is a perfectly valid.

```
public class Foo
{
    private class Bar
    {
    }
}
```